# Question on Final Fantasy 13's plot

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I am not too far into the game (just started Chapter 6).  The thing is I last played the game a while ago and am picking it up again, forgetting some of the story. I read through the data log and am pretty much caught up but had one question.

Spoilers ahead:

> As I remember it, the main cast was caught up in the Purge early on in the game and ended up falling down to the frozen lake after dealing with the Pulse fal'cie and getting branded. My question is, does the Sanctum know for sure that they are branded and are actually Pulse l'cie or is the Sanctum chasing them just because they are civilians that escaped the Purge and may be tainted? I can't remember a specific scene where their nature as l'cie was actually revealed to the Sanctum.

If anyone can shed some light on this for me (without spoiling any future developments) that would be great.

Comment: I want to edit the title to make the question more specific to the actual question being asked (in its current form, it's not very searchable or super useable for other people that may have the same question)... I'm not sure how to do that without making the title spoiler-y, though. Hmm...

Comment: fwiw, the lake isn't frozen. It's crystal.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear if the Sactum *actually* know that they were branded and Pulse L'cie, but according to [Purge wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Purge), PSICOM was sent into to hunt them down regardless and apprehend them

**I'm rephrasing the content from the wiki to avoid spoilers**

> After Lightning, Snow, Sazh, Vanille, and Hope have been turned into Pulse l'Cie, PSICOM is dispatched to hunt down them and the other Purge survivors

Actual content

> After Lightning, Snow, Sazh, and Hope have been turned into Pulse l'Cie, PSICOM is dispatched to hunt down them, Vanille, and the other Purge survivors.

In the section when Snow is attack by PSICOM they locate Snow and say

> L'cie spotted ..... Pusle L'cie confirmed.

We can see this in [this Youtube](https://youtu.be/SOimFY_yjYo?t=5125) video

This quote can be understood that they have a general idea they were L'cie, but required confirmation.